# Making an f bomb counter discord bot, Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

I want to make an f bomb counter. So I was looking at the discordjs.guide on squelize and dbs and I honestly found it annoying because it was acting as if I already knew everything it was trying to teach. To me it just lacks a lot of explenation (I just get easily confused by a lot of things). What I want to do is have a database like so:

```
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});


const Tags = sequelize.define('f_bombs', {
    chatnname: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
    },
    fbomb_count: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
    }, //<- basically a db that holds an f_bomb count for each chat the bot is in

//and then having something like this code below that interacts with the db I made, or somewhat made

bot.on('message', message=>{
 if(message.content.includes('fart')) {

   f_bombs[message.guild.id]++; //f_bombs

}
}
});
```

However I don't know how to store a variable (that holds the f bomb count) for each discord server that uses the bot that doesn't resest every time I turn off the bot (that's why I want to use a database). If any one of you guys finds a website other than discordjs.guide that can help me, that will much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i don't recommend that guide. I suggest looking at this guide and adapting it to fit your needs.  https://anidiots.guide/coding-guides/sqlite-based-points-system

This example counts every time a user sends any message, instead add an IF MESSAGE CONTAINS F-BOMB check, then add points.